# ChartJs hiding odd index values on x-axes/labels values

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

```
["06月10日","06月13日","06月14日","06月15日","06月16日","06月17日","06月20日","06月21日","06月22日","06月23日","06月24日","06月27日","06月28日","06月29日","06月30日","07月01日","07月04日","07月05日","07月06日","07月07日","07月08日","07月11日","07月12日","07月13日","07月14日","07月15日","07月19日","07月20日","07月21日","07月22日","07月25日","07月26日","07月27日","07月28日","07月29日","08月01日","08月02日","08月03日","08月04日","08月05日","08月08日","08月09日","08月10日","08月12日","08月15日","08月16日","08月17日"]
```

above are all the labels that I want to show on the graph but it hiding all the odd index values from the graph only showing even index values on the graph from the above list.
see the graph it missing some labels.
if you see the order all the even number index values are displayed and odd are hidden..

This is all my chart code...

[image: chart image with labels]

```
const data = {
            labels: dates,
            datasets: [{
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Line graph',
                data: line,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: '#ff5252',
                backgroundColor: '#ff5252',
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-a',
                lineTension: 0.1,
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 4,
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
            },{
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'Bar graph',
                data: diff,
                borderColor: colors,
                backgroundColor: colors,
                borderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 7,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                fill: true,
                showLabelBackdrop:true,
            },]
        };
        const config = {
            type:"scatter",
            data: data,
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                responsive: false,
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        display:false,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        ticks: {
                            color: "#ffffff",
                            font: {
                                size: 14,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                plugins: {
                    labels: {
                        ticks:{
                            font: {
                            size: 22
                        },
                            color: "#ffffff",
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: title,
                        padding: {
                            top: 10,
                            bottom: 30,
                        },
                        font: {
                            size: 22,
                        },
                        color: "#ffffff"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        const ctx = document.querySelector(`#chart${index+1}`).getContext('2d');
        
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config)
```

I have also tried..
`x:{ticks:{autoSkip:false}}`
when I do this it changes my label to numbers..
[image: image after adding autoSkip=false]

Comment: I see you are using a scatter chart even if, having a look to the picture,  it doesn't seem to be the correct choice. X axis, in scatter chart, is a linear axis. Maybe you can try with type: 'bar' where X axis by default is a category axis.

Comment: Thank you very much I got it..it was the issue about the linear and scatter..scatter automatically define the x axes and y axes but in linear we define it manually.
by using the linear we can use the xAxisID to autoSkip=false.and this will solve the probelm

Answer (score -1):

when you are using the **type:"scatter",**
**Scatter charts** are based on basic line charts with the x axis changed to a linear axis. To use a scatter chart, data must be passed as objects containing X and Y properties. The example below creates a scatter chart with 4 points[link for charts scatter charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html)

when you are not defining the values with x and y then used the x-axis and y-axis as linear and then you can manipulate the x-axes for both line and bar..if you will not provide the chart_type in config it will take axes as linear
you can
xAxisID: 'x-axis-bar',
xAxisID: 'x-axis-line',
and then hide the 1 x-axis and autoSkip=False it will show your all values.
I am attaching the all code below..

```
const data = {
            labels: dates,
            datasets: [{
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Line graph',
                data: line,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: '#ff5252',
                backgroundColor: '#ff5252',
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-a',
                xAxisID: 'x-axis-line',
                lineTension: 0.5,
                order:1,
            },{
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'Bar graph',
                data: diff,
                borderColor: colors,
                backgroundColor: colors,
                borderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 5,
                xAxisID: 'x-axis-bar',
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 7,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                fill: true,
                showLabelBackdrop:true,
                order:2
            },]
        };
        const config = {
            data: data,
            options: {
                responsive: false,
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        display:false,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        ticks: {
                            color: "#ffffff",
                            font: {
                                size: 14,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    'x-axis-bar':{
                        ticks:{
                            autoSkip:false,
                            stepSize:1.0,
                        }
                    },
                    'x-axis-line':{
                      display:false  
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    labels: {
                        ticks:{
                            font: {
                            size: 22
                        },
                            color: "#ffffff",
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: title,
                        padding: {
                            top: 10,
                            bottom: 30,
                        },
                        font: {
                            size: 22,
                        },
                        color: "#ffffff"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        const ctx = document.querySelector(`#chart${index+1}`).getContext('2d');
        
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config)
```

Comment: this is invalid config, linear is not a chart type

Comment: yeah it not chart type I think this will be the axis type
but it works for me.